# There's a zombie in my closet!

Tags: dying-light

So in the quest "Health Potion" I had to go to a specific apartment to find some insulin. While searching the apartment I also opened a closet and a Zombie (normal Biter) jumped straight at me. Now I was pretty shocked because after 15 hours of this game I never experienced a jumpscare and I was completely unprepared.

After this I wanted to ask some questions about zombies and closets:

- Are Closet-Zombies Random or only at fixed points in the game (like this specific apartment)
- Can there be other types of Zombies in closets? I only found a biter so  far but who knows...
- Can Zombies be hidden in other containers like cars for example?

Comment: Reading this, I should be happy that the game doesn't run on my PC (Or on any AMD hardware). I am sensitive to jumpscares :c

Comment: Bah I've played 32 hours of this game and I haven't even gotten a closet zombie :(

Comment: I've had a zombie bust out of a shed right as I passed by it.

Comment: There are a couple of other jump scares that are deliberately placed, in other missions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if someone can answer that for sure but after 2 playthroughs i would say those Closet-Zombies are random, can have different types (i found Biters, Gastanks and Toads so far) and can be found either in closets or in locked Vans (found 2 Gastanks and 1 Biter in such Vans).

Just found [**this video on Youtube**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJloRbIX0Vo) maybe it's another place than yours.